# Can't set synaptics "TapButton" options in 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics, input-devices

I have recently upgraded my netbook from Ubuntu 11.04 to 12.04 LTS. Since the upgrade - in fact, possibly since the upgrade to 11.10 - the system no longer registers touchpad taps as mouse clicks (except, bizarrely enough, in a couple of very limited cases). This feature worked perfectly in 11.04, (and before that, in Eeebuntu based on Jaunty,) and I can't get used to working without it. Other advanced touchpad options, like two-finger scrolling, work perfectly.

"Enable mouse clicks with touchpad" is enabled in System Settings. In the GPointing Device Settings GUI, tapping likewise appears enabled. Here is the output of "synclient":

```
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge                = 1775
RightEdge               = 5505
TopEdge                 = 1648
BottomEdge              = 4602
FingerLow               = 25
FingerHigh              = 30
FingerPress             = 256
MaxTapTime              = 350
MaxTapMove              = 350
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
FastTaps                = 0
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 110
HorizScrollDelta        = 110
VertEdgeScroll          = 0
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0361598
TrackstickSpeed         = 40
EdgeMotionMinZ          = 30
EdgeMotionMaxZ          = 160
EdgeMotionMinSpeed      = 1
EdgeMotionMaxSpeed      = 442
EdgeMotionUseAlways     = 0
TouchpadOff             = 0
LockedDrags             = 1
LockedDragTimeout       = 550
RTCornerButton          = 0
RBCornerButton          = 0
LTCornerButton          = -70
LBCornerButton          = 8
TapButton1              = 0
TapButton2              = 0
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 0
ClickFinger2            = 0
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 1
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 27
VertHysteresis          = 27
ClickPad                = 0
```

Now the bizarre part: "synclient TapButton1=1" has no effect whatsoever. I can set OTHER variables but not TapButton1, TapButton2 or TapButton3.

What's wrong? And how can it be fixed?